# Styling Form with Label above Inputs

Tags: html, css

I would like to produce the following form style:

```
Name                    Email
[.................]     [.................]

Subject
[.................]

Message
[.........................................]
[.........................................]
[.........................................]
[.........................................]
```

The HTML code I have is:

```
<form name="message" method="post">
    <section>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" value="" name="name">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" value="" name="email">
    </section>
    <section>
    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <input id="subject" type="text" value="" name="subject">
    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <input id="message" type="text" value="" name="message">
    </section>
</form>
```

At the moment it is producing:

```
Name    [...................]
Email   [...................]
Subject [...................]
Message
[.........................................]
[.........................................]
[.........................................]
[.........................................]
```

What would be the best way to do this? I keep getting in a muddle my floats!

Comment: Check out `display: inline-block` I much prefer it to floats for laying out forms. Beware of space between your elements, using Django I use `{% spaceless %}` a built-in template mechanism.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

I'd make both the `input` and `label` elements `display: block` , and then split the name label & input, and the email label & input into `div's` and float them next to each other.

```css
input, label {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<form name="message" method="post">
    <section>

  <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" value="" name="name">
  </div>

  <div style="float:left;">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" value="" name="email">
  </div>

  <br style="clear:both;" />

    </section>

    <section>

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <input id="subject" type="text" value="" name="subject">
    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <input id="message" type="text" value="" name="message">

    </section>
</form>
```

Comment: what? You can style a `<br>` tag?!

Answer (score 20):

Probably a bit late but this worked for me.
i simply used column flex-direction on the label and input elements
HTML

```
<form id="survey-form">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email">
  </form>

CSS

label,input{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could try something like

```
<form name="message" method="post">
    <section>
    <div>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input id="name" type="text" value="" name="name">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input id="email" type="text" value="" name="email">
    </div>
    </section>
    <section>
    <div>
      <label for="subject">Subject</label>
      <input id="subject" type="text" value="" name="subject">
    </div>
    <div class="full">
      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <input id="message" type="text" value="" name="message">
    </div>
    </section>
</form>
```

and then css it like

```
form { width: 400px; }
form section div { float: left; }
form section div.full { clear: both; }
form section div label { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old one with an accepted answer, and that answer works great.. IF you are not styling the background and floating the final inputs left. If you are, then the form background will not include the floated input fields.

To avoid this make the divs with the smaller input fields inline-block rather than float left.

This:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:20px;">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" value="" name="name">
</div>
```

Rather than:

```
<div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" value="" name="name">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd prefer not to use an HTML5 only element such as `<section>`. Also grouping the input fields might painful if you try to generate the form with code. It's always better to produce similar markup for each one and only change the class names. Therefore I would recommend a solution that looks like this :

CSS

```
label, input {
    display: block;
}
ul.form {
    width  : 500px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin : 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul.form li  {
    width : 500px;
}
ul.form li input {
    width : 200px;
}
ul.form li textarea {
    width : 450px;
    height: 150px;
}
ul.form li.twoColumnPart {
    float : left;
    width : 250px;
}
```

HTML

```
<form name="message" method="post">
    <ul class="form">
        <li class="twoColumnPart">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" type="text" value="" name="name">
        </li>
        <li class="twoColumnPart">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input id="email" type="text" value="" name="email">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <input id="subject" type="text" value="" name="subject">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea id="message" type="text" name="message"></textarea>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: If you want to use SCSS, you could nest it like this:
ul.form{
    width: 500px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
 li{
  width: 500px;
  input{
   width: 200px;
  }
  textarea{
   width: 450px;
   height: 150px;
  }
  &.twoColumnPart{
   float: left;
   width: 250px;
  }
 }
}

Answer (score 4):

Using `flex-direction: column;` on the label elements will place the labels above their boxes, however it will also lock all the boxes in a long column. To get more than one box per line, with the label above the boxes you must pair them with divs. Here is an example of both:

```css
#survey-form1 label {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

#survey-form2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.inputPair {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 10px
}
```

```html
<form id="survey-form1">
  <label for="name1">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name1">

  <label for="email1">Email</label>
  <input type="email" id="email">
</form>

<form id="survey-form2">
  <div class="inputPair">
    <label for="name2">Name2</label>
    <input type="text" id="name2">
  </div>
<div class="inputPair">
  <label for="email2">Email2</label>
  <input type="email" id="email2">
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to add any extra div wrapper as others suggest.

The simplest way is to wrap your input element inside a related label tag and set input style to `display:block`.

Bonus point earned: now you don't need to set the labels `for` attribute. Because every label target the nested input.

```
<form name="message" method="post">
    <section>
        <label class="left">
            Name
            <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
        </label>
        <label class="right">
            Email
            <input id="email" type="text" name="email">
        </label>
    </section>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Tomanek1/sguh5k17/15/

Comment: This doesn't work on Chrome today, the Subject input box interleaves in a weird way with the Name label+input.. I think Flexbox with column order or simply a good old <table> is more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

10 minutes ago i had the same problem of place label above input

then i got a small ugly resolution

```
<form>
    <h4><label for="male">Male</label></h4>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="male">
</form>
```

The disadvantage is that there is a big blank space between the label and input, of course you can adjust the css

Demo at:
http://jsfiddle.net/bqkawjs5/

Answer (score -1):

OR....you can use flexbox with flex-direction: column on the imputs and they will arrange like bliss.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).