# How can I get my html5 labels to show up like in this picture

Tags: html, forms

How can I get my labels to show up the way they are in this picture?
[image: photo from my questionnaire]

I need them both on the top and on the sides just like in the photo.  Thanks in advance.

here's the coding I have so far

```
<form>
    <div id="ab">
        <label>This is question number 01</label>
        <br />
        <label for="q1a1">1</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q1a1">
        <label for="q1a2">2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q1a2">
        <label for="q1a2">3</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q1a3">
        <label for="q1a2">4</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q1a4">
        <label for="q1a2">5</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q1a5">
        <label for="q1a2">6</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q1a6">
        <label for="q1a2">7</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q1a7">
        <label for="q1a2">8</label>
        <input type="radio" name="question01" id="q1a8">
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where are they showing up now?

Comment: actually that's from a questionnaire I designed in Indesign and am attempting to code in HTML5... so I don't really have much to show, I just got to that point and realized I need to know how to do this.

Comment: ok how can I paste the code in here?

Answer (score 1):

Similar questions have been asked and answered on this site. Take a look at the accepted answer for the attached post.

[styling with label above inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046110/styling-form-with-label-above-inputs)

Essentially what you can do is use the display: block CSS style within a single div for each number label and radio input select. This will stack the two elements instead of using the default inline display styling.

```
/** two labels on each side of your scale*/
.end-label {
    float:left;
}
/** for div containing label over radio input */
.label-radiobtn-div {
    float: left;
}

/** inner label and radio components of   containing div, this will force each element on its own line */
.label-radiobtn-div input,
.label-radiobtn-div label {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: ok are those class names you came up with?  Or are those actual things, like if you were to set a style to the body you'd type .body { stuff }?

Comment: Those are just random class names I used to help describe what I was trying to show, nothing special. That is almost correct it would be just body { stuff} the dot is used for classes the built in tags only require the tag name for styling.