# What makes a label tag not to be able to be "on top" of an input tag?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In this page:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons

If you change the Go! `button` to a label (with the Chrome inspector) you'll notice that the Go! button is not longer on top of the input field:

[image]

(Instead of the borders to be one on top of the other they are side by side.)

Why is this and how to make the two elements to be one on top of another?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap applies `max-width:100%` to a label. That shrinks its border box (`box-sizing:border-box` is applied throughout) such that that fits inside its containing block (its parent span element), whose width is reduced by one pixel because that is determined by the fact that it must contain the margin box of the Go! button/label which has `margin-right:-1px` applied. The span is the button/label's containing block because its input-group-btn class makes it `display:table-cell`

So to get the same effect with a label, just set `label { max-width:none; }` In practice, you will probably want a more specific selector.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a label on top of an input isn't the best idea, it would be better to split them up and have them float next to each other. This question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046110/styling-form-with-label-above-inputs) may help. This could also be adjusted using the z-index in the style portion of each div. As to answer you title in why this happens, i'm not entirely sure...