# Is it possible to place the label text above the input when wrapping the label around the input?

Tags: html, css

I want to have the label text on top of the input when using the wrapping method, i.e.

```
<label>
   Label Text:
   <input type="text">
</label>
```

The following post is using the label with the `for` attribute and therefore the label and input elements are separated: [Styling Form with Label above Inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046110/styling-form-with-label-above-inputs)

But is it possible in the way I wrote above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```css
label input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label>
   Label Text:
   <input type="text">
</label>
```

Comment: Oh, so simple! instead of wrapping the text in a span and giving it a `display: block;`. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible to show label on top of the input with the mentioned above html. Please check CSS :-

```css
label {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
label input {
    grid-column: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Label Text on Top of Input</title>
</head>
<body>

<label>
   Label Text:
   <input type="text">
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply wrap the label in a div:

```html
<label>
   <div>Label Text:</div>
   <input type="text">
</label>
```

Alternatively you could use a line break:

```html
<label>
   Label Text:<br>
   <input type="text">
</label>
```

Comment: I just read that according to the specs, placing `div` inside a `label` is technically not correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609554/is-div-inside-label-block-correct. Perhaps it's outdated or just doesn't matter? So maybe I can instead use `span` and give it `display: block;`?

Comment: Correct, according to the HTML spec you cannot have block-level elements (div) inside inline elements (label). It will still work, but if you prefer you can indeed use a `span` with `display: block`. Perhaps even simpler you can just use a `<br>` tag—I've updated my answer with that alternative solution.

Comment: Oh that's also a nice solution. Hard to decide which one is better: This one with the `<br>`, or the one using `display:block;` on the `input` (The other answer). It really looks like yours is simpler now because it's all in one place